# В windows 7 всё работает, а в  windoes 8 NullPointException

Tags: android-studio

Такая ситуация странная. Мой проект хорошо запускается и работает под windows 7 и в Ubuntu, а вот под windows 8 выдает ошибку NullPointException.

С чем это может быть связанно?

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.ldpr.balashov.ldprbeta/ru.ldpr.balashov.ldpr.NewsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ru.ldpr.balashov.ldpr.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: У меня щас мозг взорвётся... Activity... это же класс Андроида. Каким боком тут винда?

Comment: @argamidon Да, вы правильно подметили насчёт Activity, но вот ничего не меня в коде, в одной ОС запускается без ошибок, а в другой - с ошибкой.

Comment: > Да, вы правильно подметили насчёт Activity

вот именно что правильно. Причем тут винда, если у вас андроид-приложение?

Comment: @smilemakc `at ru.ldpr.balashov.ldpr.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.java:56)` стек трейс говорит нам, что, вероятно, причина там.

Comment: @DreamChild Тогда почему же что на семерке и в убунте идет без проблем и ошибок, а в восмерке сразу же выдает ошибку, хотя код не менялся?

Comment: У меня на работе рядом стоят два компьютера, на одном семерка, на другом восмерка. Подключаю телефон на к семерошному компу, запускаю проект через студио, всё работает. Этот же код  с восмерошного компа на этот же телефон выдает ошибку

Comment: @smilemakc что с зависимостями-библиотеками стронними? Версии IDE и  android API на тех компах одинаковые?

Comment: @argamidon проект добавляю через git, все зависимости прописаны в gradle. На обоих одни и те же версии Студии и SDK так же одинаковые. На восмерошном компе стоит ещё и Убунта, так в ней так же хорошо всё работает. Мне просто совсем непонятно, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: может быть, семерка x86, а восьмерка x64